# SQL Server order by case

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I want to create a fourth column with this `query`:

```
select * from (select ID, column0, column1, column2, column3 = Case when 
column2 = '' then column1 else column2 end, row_number() over(partition by 
column0 order by [column3]) as column4 from myTable) ti
```

But this error appears:

```
Invalid column name 'column3'.
```

I want this result: (red marked column):

[image: Example]

Comment: Don't order by `[column3]`, order by the case statement itself.

Comment: This not works 
`select * from (select ID, column0, column1, column2, column3 = Case when 
column2 = '' then column1 else column2 end, row_number() over(partition by 
column0 order by Case when 
column2 = '' then column1 else column2 end) as column4 from myTable) ti `    
All the rows of the 4th column are `1`.

Comment: Only a Sith does day first in their short dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use order by from outside of subquery as below:

```
Select *, row_number() over(partition by 
 column3 order by [Id]) as column4 
 from (select ID, column0, column1, column2, column3 = Case when 
      column2 = '' then column1 else column2 end 
        from myTable) ti
```

For your 4th column in image you need to partition by column3 order by id. If you do Partition by column0 then you will get all 1's

Comment: Thanks this works, its true the condition for the 4th column is like you say.

Answer (score 0):

This way it will work:

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by 
column0 order by [column3]) as column4 from 
(select ID, column0, column1, column2, column3 = Case when 
column2 = '' then column1 else column2 end from myTable) ti
```